# Stuck on a systems of linear equations question

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I am completing a practice questions sheet for the topic "systems of linear of equations" and I've hit a roadblock on one of the questions.

1.
Consider the system of equations
$$\begin{aligned} x + 2y - z &= -3 \\\ \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} 3x + 5y + kz &= -4 \\\ \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} 9x + (k+13)y + 6z &= 9 \\\ \end{aligned}$$
a) Express these equations as an augmented matrix

which I think is (correct me if I'm wrong):
**$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 2 & -1 & -3 \\
    3 & 5 & k & -4 \\
    9 & (k+13) & 6 & 9
  \end{array}\right]
$$**

I am stuck on part (b) which is:

b) Show that this matrix can be row-reduced to

**$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 2 & -1 & -3 \\
    0 & 1 & -k-3 & -5 \\
    0 & 0 & k^2-2k & 5k+11 
  \end{array}\right]
$$**

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: as suggested by siong below I performed R2−3R1 , R3−9R1, but the matrix I got had several differences to the one in the question. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, missing a step, or if the answer in the question is incorrect and I just need to state that it is.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Perform $R_2-3R_1$, $R_3-9R_1$, $-R_2$, and you should be one step away from the solution.

Comment: so after performing the row operations, there were some parts that differ from the given matrix, such as -k+3 rather than -k-3. Would I, therefore, record the correct row echelon form and state that the given matrix is incorrect?

Comment: First, check if you have copied the question correctly. If it is correct, you might like to consider special values of $k$, for example let $k=0$. Check with a numerical solver  if the matrices are row equivalent.

Comment: sorry I just checked and I miss wrote the question. its my first time using mathjax

Comment: I have corrected the question, I apologize for that I should've noticed sooner

Comment: I redid it after fixing the errors however I still dont understand how you get the 0 in place of the (k+13) and where the (k^2-2k) and (5k+11) in the questions answer are coming from

Comment: After you perform all those steps, your $(2,2)$ entry should be $1$. Your $(2,1)$ and $(3,1)$ entries shoul dbe $0$. Suppose your $(3,2)$ entry is $c$, what should you multiply to $R_2$ and then add to $R_3$ in a typical Gaussian elimination step?

Comment: I'm really not sure I can't seem to get my head around the k^2-2k and the 5k+11. If you do R3-k+5R2 that cancels out the k-5 to 0, but I'm pretty sure that isn't correct

Comment: You should do $R_3+(5-k)R_2$.